# end matching after first occurance of a word - bash regex

Tags: regex, bash, regex-group

could you help me create correct regex in bash?

What I need to do is to extract each table definition from structure like:

```
    OID: 123
    Name: tab1
    CREATE TABLE tab1 (
       ...
       );

    OID: 456
    Name: tab2
    CREATE TABLE tab2 (
       ...
       );

    OID: 789
    Name: tab3
    CREATE TABLE tab3 (
       ...
       );
```

prepared one line format:

```
OID: 123 Name: tab1 CREATE TABLE tab1 ( ... ); OID: 456 Name: tab2 CREATE TABLE tab2 ( ... ); OID: 789 Name: tab3 CREATE TABLE tab3 ( ... );
```

I have to get all text between words `Name` and `OID`.
I wrote simple loop that preparing specific regex for each table name but I have a problem with matching.

For each table name my regex is something like:

```
(Name: tab2 .*?)( OID: .*)
```

My result is :

```
Name: tab2 CREATE TABLE tab2 ( ... )
```

I tested above regex in Online regex simulator and it's working. I just extract first group from full matching.
Batch regex doesn't grouping it properly. I think batch doesn't know ? (zero or one occurrences of the preceding element). I have no result using above regex in bash.

My bash command is something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
tables_definition=$(less tables_definition.txt)
regex="(Name: tab2 .*?)( OID: .*)"

    if [[ $tables_definition =~ $regex ]];
      then
        object_definition="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"     

        #do something
    fi
```

Please help.

Comment: can you post the bash command you're using?

Comment: just edited my post

Comment: `.*?` is a problem -- POSIX ERE (the standard to which bash's regexes comply) doesn't have non-greedy globs. (The regex engine isn't actually built into bash, but provided by your operating system's C library, so the implementation can vary a bit from platform to platform -- but the calls it uses are required to implement the ERE standard; anything additional is a platform-specific extension).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @CharlesDuffy.

Comment: @MrF : I'd be interested to know your reg-ex background. From old unix days, only the Perlies could use `.*?`, etc., but now people post Qs all the time asking for *nix solutions using lookbehinds, non-greedy quantifiers etc. What was your exposure to regex that helped you compose your regex as above?  And as always, good luck solving your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Bash's regexes don't support "frugal quantifiers".

What about using `grep` with PCRE?

```
grep -Po '(?<=Name: tab. ).*?(?= OID: .*|$)'
```

It returns all the three definitions from your one-line string.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.
I received:
`pcregrep: Error in command-line regex at offset 31: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length`

What's more, it's important to get those definitioins one by one. That's why I put it in loop.

Comment: @MrF: You probably used a non-fixed length in the `(?<=...)` part. You can always read the definitions one by one from grep.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS=OFS=" "}{$1=$1;print}' file
OID: 123 Name: tab1 CREATE TABLE tab1 ( ... ); OID: 456 Name: tab2 CREATE TABLE tab2 ( ... ); OID: 789 Name: tab3 CREATE TABLE tab3 ( ... );
```

The trailing newline is also missing (due to `ORS=" "`). If needed, add `END{print "\n"}` to the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

A Bash solution. The input file contains the table definition in one line format (not necessarily):

```
    shopt -s extglob

    table_definition=$( cat table_definition.txt )
    table_definition=${table_definition//OID: +([[:digit:]]) Name: tab+([[:digit:]] )/}
    table_definition=${table_definition//; /;\\n}

    echo -e $table_definition
```

The first parameter substitution deletes all `OID: xxx Name: tabx`, the second one adds a newline to all semicolons.

The output:

```
    CREATE TABLE tab1 ( ... );
    CREATE TABLE tab2 ( ... );
    CREATE TABLE tab3 ( ... );
```

If the input file is not a oneliner use

```
    table_definition=$( cat table_definition2.txt | tr -d "\n" | tr -s ' ')
```

to delete newlines and sqeeze the blanks.